# how to rewrite a custom url in joomla using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla2.5

I am designing a News Website using joomla 2.5

I want rewrite this url:

`http://domain.com/categoryname/?format=feed&type=rss`

to:

`http://domain.com/rss/categoryname`

**Note**: I'm using mode_rewrite .htaccess for joomla.

please help me quickly.
thanks to every body in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache's `mod_rewrite` allows you to transform a url to a different url utilizing regex patterns.

The pattern applies to the path and allows you to do your in your example write a regex pattern like `/rss/(.+)` which will match anything beginning with `/rss/` and has at least one character after.  The parenthesis are called a capturing group and you can reference that in the second parameter in the `RewriteRule` directive.

The second part `/$1/?format=feed&type=rss`, references the first captured group in the pattern and places it in the new url.

Finally you want to signify that it is the last rule to be processed with an `[L]` flag.

This gives you a rule of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /rss/(.+) /$1/?format=feed&type=rss [L]
```

If you intend to pass query strings to this new url, you will need to add an additional flag `QSA` which will result in `[L,QSA]` in place of `[L]`.